# Associating onDraw(View view) with SurfaceView

Tags: java, android

For starters, personally I've always found it hard to understand what happens to code automatically versus manually. One area where I'm particularly having trouble is understanding the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method of the android.view.View class in android development. I have some code with no errors but when it runs my onDraw(Canvas canvas) seems to be ignored. I do not think the compiler knows where I want to draw and I do not know how to let it know. Here's some of my code (only adding relevant code. If you need more just comment and I'll add more accordingly):

Main Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    backGround = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bG);
    GFX screen = new GFX();
}
```

GFX

```
public class GFX extends Activity{
    MyBringBack ourView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceCreate){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceCreate);
        ourView = new MyBringBack(this);
        setContentView(ourView);
    }
}
```

MyBringBack

```
public class MyBringBack extends View {

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public MyBringBack(Context context){
        super(context);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);

    }

}
```

I've been following [these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3) tutorials on youtube.

**How do I specify where I want to draw?**

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually discovered myself just adding `setContentView(new MyBringBack(this));` does the trick

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing here. You should not be instantiating an Activity in another activity. Can you elaborate?

As for why onDraw doesn't work. It might be because you should call

```
 Canvas.save()
```

after your drawing is done. additionally if you want to make sure that the ondraw gets called you need to do

```
someView.invalidate()
```

this will tell the view to call

```
onMeasure and onDraw
```